# Clicking noise when I brake or slow down or drive over a bump

Tags: honda, noise, civic

I recently hit a footpath, where my front left tyre rim got bent and had changed the tyre and the rim, but unfortunately I didn’t notice that i had a worn out mount on my right side of engine which caused a huge vibration. I had replaced the engine mount as well which resolved the issue.

Post that I notice a crackling noise when I go over a bump or a rough surface. What could you’ll think the problem would have been? My car is a Honda Civic 2007 Automatic and has driven 130000 Kms.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The suspension may have been damaged when you hit the footpath (in the USA we call that a hitting a curb) It may be the shock absorber took damage and thats why it rides rough over bumps now.